# Why does Date#getHours() return hour + 1?

Tags: javascript, date

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/8EK8x/) is my code:

```
var feedDataTimestamp = new Date("2014-01-14T00:04:40+0000").getTime();
var parsedDate = new Date(+feedDataTimestamp);
alert(parsedDate.getHours());
```

but it should print 0, not 1: time is `00:04:40`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you (according to your Stackoverflow profile) are in Italy, so your time zone is UTC+1.

The time stamp you are inputting is UTC+0.

`parsedDate` will be in local time.

Use [the `getUTCHours()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) if you want to get UTC time instead of local time.

Answer (score 1):

You set the timezone in the parsed string as `+0000` so you seem to want the hours in UTC, use

```
alert(parsedDate.getUTCHours())
```